# Running Get command on EC2 from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS environment.I have installed apache Atlas in EC2 instance and from Lambda I am trying to get metadata from glue data catalog and post it in apache atlas(apache atlas uses rest end-points) running on ec2.I am able to get the glue data catalog metadata in lambda function.

How can i access use curl/httpGet call from lambda function to access service running on port 21000 on localhost on my EC2 instance?

Update1 : Resolved by allowing all traffic for inbound on private IP for the EC2 instance in security group.

Update2 : Now I am able to access the rest URL(by its private IP) and glue catalog both within Lambda.What I did is I created a private and public subnet and put my EC2 instance and lambda on same private subnet with NAT configured on a public subnet.

Now my lambda is working but I am not able to ssh on my EC2 instance.Is there a way to get that working also?

Comment: For the latest issue you posted: when Lambda runs inside a VPC, it can't get an internet connection by default, and to reach your EC2 instance, it needs internet access. In order to enable it, you need a NAT Gateway; follow these instructions: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: @RenatoByrro but then how am I able to reach public IP of service running on EC2 instance by Lambda?

Comment: Yes. When a Lambda runs inside a VPC, it can't make external connections. By following the tutorial I send, you'd be able to reach any public IP from your Lambda.

Comment: @RenatoByrro Now my Lambda works fine and is able to access EC2 via its private IP,but now I am not able to ssh into my EC2 instance as it lives in private VPC.Is there a way to get around that also?

Comment: Good that you made progress. Follow this tutorial and you'll be good to go: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/. As a suggestion, following the Stackoverflow community rules, always try as much as you can to find an answer by yourself first. Post here only when you're unable to solve the issue. About your last update, I did a quick search for "AWS EC2 ssh vpc" and found that tutorial. You could have done the same... It's just a suggestion to ensure a healthy community for everyone. ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"localhost" is relative to each computer. What is "localhost" on your EC2 server is different from what is "localhost" on AWS Lambda, etc. You need to stop trying to access "locahost" and use the server's IP address instead.

To access port `21000` on the EC2 server the Lambda function needs to be placed in the same VPC that the EC2 instance is in, and the EC2 server needs to be listening to external traffic on port `21000`, not just localhost traffic. You would assign a security group to the Lambda function, and in the security group assigned to the EC2 server you would open port `21000` for traffic coming from the Lambda function's security group. Finally, the Lambda function would access the EC2 server by addressing it via the server's private IP.

Comment: I am now able to connect to ec2 service via internet.But i am not able to connect it through lambda.I have tried both public and private address.

Comment: The solution to your issue of not being able to access some services when the Lambda function is in the VPC is to create one or more private subnets in your VPC that has a NAT gateway, and place the Lambda function in those subnets so that it will use the NAT gateway to access things that exist outside the VPC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Apache Atlas and whether it exposes it's own HTTP endpoints to external clients. What you need is a server running on EC2 for that.

EC2 server doesn't magically accept HTTP calls from external connections and route to the local resources you want (in this case, Atlas). Install Apache Server, nginx or any other server in your EC2 instance. Configure it properly and write some code that takes the data POSTed by your Lambda and submits to the local Apache Atlas API.

The following page contains some instructions in this direction. Search the web if you need more help, there are tons of tutorials for doing this already. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html

Comment: Yes it does exposes rest endpoints..so it have exposed some rest endpoints over localhost and i need to access those endpoints from lambda

Comment: Are those endpoints configured to accept HTTP calls from external clients? They must be otherwise you will only be able to call Atlas from within the EC2, not from Lambda.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to Atlas from a client other than Lambda (say `curl` or `wget` in the command line)? Something like `POST/GET http://ec2-ip-address/atlas/endpoint/`. If yes, does it work? If it doesn't work, it's not a problem with Lambda, but the configuration of your Atlas server.

Comment: Yes,Now I am able to access after allowing inbound traffic for HTTP on port 21000.But I am facing another issue, I have updated the question above.